# Over seeding grass timing in fall when little-to-no rain in future

Tags: grass, dryness, overseeding, fall-gardening

I have around 4 acres of lawn area in Northern Ohio that I want to over-seed.

I've already started preparing by mowing the grass low (2") and did one pass of plug aerating.  My plan was to wait until the next time it was going to rain for a few days in a row, then mow low again, do another pass of aeration, and seed before the rain comes.

The problem is, there's almost no rain in the forecast except for a 60% chance of morning thunderstorms on one day.  And, it's supposed to be in the mid 80s the couple days after.

I could seed just before that potential rain, but... is it worth trying knowing that it's not going to rain for the 10+ days following?  Or should I wait until later in the fall and hope sometime in early Oct has a few days of rain and is cooler?